# how to additional series as line chart on column chart

Tags: highcharts

I want to add new line chart on column chart in highcharts

[line chart http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/9335/unh.png](http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/9335/unh.png)

Just like above image, i want to have this green line chart on column chart.
how to add this additional line chart on column chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the official example here:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes